# Get cursor position in a multiline text field

Tags: java, text, swt

I try to get the line number and "columns" in a multiline text field. The problem is that if I'm using getSelection() and moving the cursor down then I will get {0:0}, {5,5}, {10,10}. But what I expect is {0,0} (first line, first column), {0,1} (second line, first column) and {0,2} (third line, first column):

```
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
  Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
  container.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  Text textBox = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);
  textBox.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true));
  textBox.setText("one\ntwo\nthree");
  textBox.setSelection(0);
  textBox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      System.out.println(textBox.getSelection());
    }
  });

  return container;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text.getSelection` always returns the offset from the start of the string of the selection. It does not know anything about lines.

So you will have to convert the offset to a line number. One possibility is to use the JFace `Document` class

```
Document doc = new Document(text);

int lineNumber = doc.getLineOfOffset(offset);
```

Or use the `StyledText` control which also has a `getLineAtOffset` and similar methods. So for example:

```
Point sel = styledText.getSelection();

int lineNumber = styledText.getLineAtOffset(sel.x);

int lineOffset = styledText.getOffsetAtLine(lineNumber);

int column = sel.x - lineOffset;
```

Comment: Ok, StyledText looks useful for my purpose. But how can I get the correct cursor position, f.e. that the cursor is placed on the first character on line 10? The getLineAtOffset method only returns the line index but not the "column" number (the X coordinate).

Comment: Added a StyledText example